# Compilation error : 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context

Tags: c++, scope, this, condition-variable

I am trying to add a `condition_variable` to handle threads, but get a compilation error at this line:

```
this->cv.wait(lk, []{return this->ready;});
```

Looks like the for the variable `this->ready`, the `this` is not in the right scope.

In Java this can be handled with `TestThread.this`, is there anything in C++ doing the same?

```
void TestThread::Thread_Activity()
    {
        std::cout << "Thread started \n";
        // Wait until ThreadA() sends data
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            this->cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
        }
    
        std::cout << "Thread is processing data\n";
        data += " after processing";
        // Send data back to ThreadA through the condition variable
        {
           // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
            processed = true;
           // std::cout << "Thread B signals data processing completed\n";
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Side note: in a different context it may be unnecessary to capture `this` at all. For example, `static` class methods and variables can be used in a lambda without capturing `this`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to capture the `this` pointer:

```
this->cv.wait(lk, [this]{return ready;});
```