# Qt5 - C++11: 'This' cannot be implicitly captured in this context

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qtextedit

I am trying to pass the result of a `qDebug()` statement into a `QTextEdit` but without success because I am getting a compiler error of `'This' cannot be implicitly captured in this context` and I have never got this error before.

Then output is coming after executing a `QProcess` and would like to show it on the `QTextEdit` I have below:

[image: lineedit]

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    startLidar();
    ui->textEditLidar->setText("[STATUS] NO PROCESS STARTED: ");
    ui->textEditGUI->setText("[STATUS] NO PROCESS STARTED: ");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::startLidar()
{
    // Execution of the QProcess to make sure Lidar App Launcher opens:
    this->executeROSLidarApp = new QProcess(this);
    this->executeROSLidarApp->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] FINISHED: " << exitCode << exitStatus;
            if(script->bytesAvailable() > 0) qDebug() << "[EXEC] buffered DATA:" << script->readAll();

            ui->textEditLidar->setText("would like to see the output of the exitCode and exitStatus"); // <-- error here

    });
    connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();

            ui->textEditLidar->setText("would like to see the output of the error"); // <-- error here
    });
}
```

I think this is connected to the different `C++` edition I am using. I have been using `C++11` and it seems to be connected to a possible lambda function compilation error.
I have been trying to research this error and came across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595834/compilation-error-this-cannot-be-implicitly-captured-in-this-context), [this additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217956/error-variable-cannot-be-implicitly-captured-because-no-default-capture-mode-h) source and everything seems to be leading to a mismatch between the different editions. In case needed I could also include my `.pro` file.

Thanks for shedding light on this issue and point to the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda does not capture `ui` or `this`, so there's no way to call `ui->textEditLidar->setText`.

Change this

```
connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();

        ui->textEditLidar->setText("would like to see the output of the error"); // <-- error here
});
```

to this

```
connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [this, script = this->executeROSLidarApp](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();

        ui->textEditLidar->setText("would like to see the output of the error"); // <-- error here
});
```

or this

```
connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [ui, script = this->executeROSLidarApp](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();

        ui->textEditLidar->setText("would like to see the output of the error"); // <-- error here
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reading the question. What should be the fix then? I have never had this error before?

Comment: @Emanuele The fix would be to either capture `this` or `ui` in the lambda, of course.

Comment: Could you please integrate some code in your answer so that I can better understand your suggestion :) ?

Comment: Oooo I got you!! that was easy!! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda does not capture this (as the error message tells you) but you're trying to access it (ui->textEditLidar->...)